# How to change column chart color programmatically

Tags: charts, views, blocks

I have created view block using different content type. I am displaying this block as a column chart using Drupal module [Highcharts](https://www.drupal.org/project/highcharts), it is working but if I want to display separate color of content type node I mean one color for one content type node and other color for other content type.
Can any one tell me how to change this? Is there any module by which I can sort out my problem?

Comment: are you using the highchart module? (https://www.drupal.org/project/highcharts)

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to answer the last question, i.e.:

> Is there any module by which I can sort out my problem?

To create charts in Drupal, consider the [comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) as a possible place to start from, to find the module that best fits your needs. That comparison does include the modules mentioned here, but quite AbitMORE charting modules ...

Possible alternatives that should solve this specific question, are the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module, or the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. I recently created quite a lot of new [Chart documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2370811), and [Charts documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753). Though there are other alternatives in that comparison that might be a better fit for this specific case.

The **license** that comes with the related charting library (engine) in each of these modules, should be considered also. It is one of the (important?) selection criteria for deciding on the module to go for. 'Possible privacy concerns' or 'Yes or no support for saving charts in PDFs' is another typical item to consider.

Be aware: I'm a new (co-) maintainer of both module 'chart' and 'charts' (confusing names, I didn't invent those names), and the author of the comparison.

Ps: the question does not say **why** it has to be done programmatically. But note that the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module ships with [out-of-the-box](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426921) samples which seems to be very close to what you are trying to create. Adapting these samples to exactly fit your needs seems like cloning these samples in a new views display or a new view.

Comment: I don't see any clear answer in this explanation.